# how to make news and articles using the same silverstripe news module?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I need to incorporate News and Announcements in my silverstripe website, both news and announcements have the exact same structure and they both use https://github.com/nyeholt/silverstripe-news. in the html template I have two sections one for the news and another for the announcements.

what is the proper way to implement this:

- should I just copy and past the /news module folder and use one for the news and the other for announcements.
- or add another db field as flag to specify if this is a news article or an announcement article, but then in the cms the user would have to check this every time.
- or is there anything else, I don't know

Comment: For sure not copy/paste. Rule of programming: Don't repeat yourself! You want to prevend to have copy/paste code. Its really bad and nearlly impossible to maintain when you're project is getting bigger.

Comment: shouldn't they be separated if there is a rule that thumbnails are required for the news and not for the announcements. and other rules.

Comment: They should always be separated. You really never should repeat yourself... The problem with finished solutions (like the one you want to use) is that its quite often not really easy to come into the code and to change it how you want. So i don't know how good your skills are... But also this simple rule for thumbnails required only for news can be done with a simple IF-Condition...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicating the folder would not have the result you expect unless youd rename all the classes in side of the new one.

Basically the folder is just a place for the classes to be, not something that you access when you actually request an news article, you use SilverStripes routes for that.

Static assets would be something that are  be loaded from a module folder.

The best way to add a new behaviour to an extension is to use a DataExtension.

See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/extending/extensions/

Other way would be if the module uses sitetree for placing the "news holder". Then you have the option also to just create two holders with different names and then if you want to show a list of a paricular parent just filter with the parentId that relates to the correct holder.

Third option would be to just would to add a new class under mysite that extends the modules classes and override only SOME of the methods to suite your needs.

Comment: I decided that I need to copy the news folder into a new module, I have read the code and it seems very easy to change. I will rename the classes (just 2 classes) (NewsArticle -> AnnouncementArticle ...etc). I think this is the best and easiest way as from my requirements, News and Announcements will differ in some way, and I don't want to use IF statements here and there.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you should do that.. There is no point changing the extensions name from news to annousments if the content is 99% the same. You only need to manage updates to two different extensions if yo go down that route.

Comment: I'v added a third option to my answer

Comment: UH.. I ment : I'd strongly suggest you should not do that :).. But of course that is also a valid way to go in some situations..

Comment: Yes I think the third option you provided is the most suitable in this case.  Thank you :)